# How do I add a .NET Core Class Library dll to ASP.Net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

when I add a .NET core class library dll to my ASP.NET core project and try to use it in my code, I get the following:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Test.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm on .NET Core 1.1 for both projects. The dll is referenced in the project. I assume I need to add the reference of this class dll in some config file but I searched everywhere and couldn't find where.

Any help would be appreciated

Patrick

Comment: When you say dll in in correct folder? what folder is it in within your ASP.NET core project? Did you right click project and select add reference? how did you add this dll to your proj?

Comment: Yes the dll is reference in the project. I right clicked project and select add reference and I can see it in there. The problem is when I publish it and run the application.

Comment: You say publish... does it run ok in debug ?

Comment: It's published in Debug mode. The application runs fine, it's just when I try calling the dll that it fails.

Comment: I assume this is a bug as i have been dealing with this all day as well.

after further research i found out this is not an issue in 1.0 but only is affecting me on 1.1.

you can replicated it very easily, make new asp.net core web application (.Net core) and a class library (.Net core). build the empty library and then go to the web application reference it and initialise the empty class. hit run, it will build but it will fail to load the library when it hits the function you have referenced the code in.

Answer (score 0):

Until they fix the issue in 1.1, if possible, if you jump back to 1.0 this should not be a problem as i can get it working fine on 1.0.